# Setting up Tornado with Nginx on Ubuntu 10.04 for production use

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04, tornado

I understand that there's an nginx configuration file at http://www.friendfeed.com
But i don't really know how to set up Tornada for production use on Ubuntu 10.04 with Nginx.

Here's my situation and assumptions:
1) Assuming my Tornado project is set up as such:

```
project/
    src/
       static/
       templates/
           project.py
```

And I have installed Tornado by downloading the repositary from Github and than `sudo python setup.py install`

2) I've installed Nginx and started it based on the instructions here : http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

My questions are:
Where does my nginx configuration file go ? Within the src/ folder?
After configuring Nginx, how do I start my Tornado project?

Comment: What is it that you want to set up nginx to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could help a lot: https://github.com/chaselee/tornado-linode

Check out the link in the Readme to see how to deploy in production on Ubuntu 10.04.

Basically I keep the nginx conf in my repo, which gets pulled into the server, and the conf file is symlinked into the actual nginx directory where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

For an EC2 Ubuntu with a default install the config file is here:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

I would recommend symlinking it like chaselee suggested